# How to create delete a row button in php

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I'm creating a simple contact system with admin page. Admin can delete messages. I use
`<form>` tag and submit button to send them to action file but no rows will be deleted.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $adminmsgn = $row['name'];
    $adminmsge = $row['email'];
    $adminmsgm = $row['msg'];
    echo("
      <form name='actions' action='delete.php' method='post'>
    <tr>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsgn</td>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsge</td>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsgm</td>
      <td style='color: white'><input style='text-decoration: none;color: white' class='linkButton' type='submit' value='Delete'></td></form>
    </tr>
    ");
}
?>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php include("connection.php");
mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `msg` WHERE `name` = '$adminmsgn' AND `email`= '$adminmsge' AND `msg`= '$adminmsgm'");
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/contact/admincp.php");
?>
```

Comment: I'm just doing this as an exercise to find my basic problems first.

Comment: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582)

Comment: Consider whether you really want to 'DELETE' data (i.e. make it irretrievable), as opposed to simply marking it as hidden

Comment: indentation and grammar changes

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs the input values, probably hidden or something.  Your form could look like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $adminmsgn=$row['name'];
    $adminmsge=$row['email'];
    $adminmsgm=$row['msg'];
    echo("
      <form name='actions' action='delete.php' method='post'>

      <input type='hidden' name='adminmsgn' value='$adminmsgn' >
      <input type='hidden' name='adminmsge' value='$adminmsge' >
      <input type='hidden' name='adminmsgm' value='$adminmsgm' >

    <tr>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsgn</td>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsge</td>
      <td style='color: white'>$adminmsgm</td>
      <td style='color: white'><input style='text-decoration: none;color: white' class='linkButton' type='submit' value='Delete'></td></form>
    </tr>
    ");
}
```

In your `delete.php` simply add get the variables from `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST.`
And it is true you are open to `SQL injection;` therefore, try use `mysql_real_escape_string` on all the post variables.  Your code should now look like this

```
<?php 
    include("connection.php");

    $adminmsgn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminmsgn']);
    $adminmsge = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminmsge']);
    $adminmsgm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminmsgm']);

    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM `msg` WHERE `name` = '$adminmsgn' AND `email`= '$adminmsge' AND `msg`= '$adminmsgm'");
        header("Location: http://localhost:8080/contact/admincp.php");
        ?>
```

Not tested but it should sure work